# Parse RSS with groovy

Tags: parsing, groovy, rss, xmlslurper

I am trying to parse RSS feeds with groovy. I just wanted to extract the title and description tags' value. I used following code snippet to achieve this:

```
rss = new XmlSlurper().parse(url)
            rss.channel.item.each {
            titleList.add(it.title)
            descriptionList.add(it.description)
            }
```

After this, I am accessing these values in my JSP page. What is going wrong is the value of description that I am getting is not just of`<description>` (child of `<channel>`) but also of`<media:description>` (another optional child of `<channel>`). What can I change to only extract the value of`<description>` and omit the value of `<media:description>`?

Edit: To duplicate this behavior, you can execute following code on this website: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php

```
 def url = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"
 rss = new XmlSlurper().parse(url)
 rss.channel.item.each {
    println"${it.title}"
    println"${it.description}"
}
```

You will see that the media description tag is also being printed in the console.

Comment: could you please either provide the mentioned url or an actual xml text, that shows the problems.

Comment: I am using this xml: http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml The results I am getting by extracting the description tag also include values of <media:description> tag. I verified it by checking the page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` to not try to handle namespaces in the constructor.  I believe this does what you are after:

```
'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml'.toURL().withReader { r ->
    new XmlSlurper(false, false).parse(r).channel.item.each {
        println it.title
        println it.description
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not to handle namespaces? I am not familiar with it

Comment: `<media:description>` is an xml tag with a namespace.  The tag is `description`, but it is in the namespace `media` (defined by `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"` in the xml).  If you tell `XmlSlurper` to not parse namespaces, then this element will need to be accessed via `it.'media:description'`

Comment: Ok. The default XMLSluper() is non-namespace-aware. That means, it tries to get any tag with the word description and is a child of channel?